# Test for empty string in Mongoose regular expression

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

Everything I've found indicates that an empty string can be matched in a regular expression by /^$/. However, that expression is not working in my Mongoose Validator for zipcode.

I want to set zipcode if one of two states is true - either it is empty or it is a valid, five digit number.

```
ZIP_REGEX: /^$|^[0-9]{5}$/
zip: {
    type: Number,
    validate: [ ZIP_REGEX, 'ValidationError']
},
```

This validator fails each time I attempt to store an empty string. The result is I can set valid zipcode, but never unset them. Is Mongoose also trying to verify that the empty string is a Number? Is the regular expression wrong?

Comment: One thing I've discovered is that if the type is String, this works fine. Not a great solution, however.

Comment: Can an empty number even exist?  How can you store an empty string in a numeric type?  How can you validate an empty string against a numeric type?

Comment: Practically speaking, yes, an empty number can exist. It's equivalent to a user saying, "I do not wish to share my zipcode with this service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom validation function for anything a bit unusual like this.  Assuming you want to support both numbers and strings as input:

```
function validator(v) {
    return (!v && v !== 0) || /^[0-9]{5}$/.test(v.toString());
};

zip: {
    type: Number,
    validate: [validator, 'ValidationError']
},
```